# Как сделать одинаковые отступы слева и справа

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Учусь верстке. Накидал себе до ужаса простой шаблон и пытаюсь его воспроизвести только уже в web. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не разберусь ни как как можно сделать, чтобы отступы были одинаковые по горизонтали. Чтобы `div`-ы шли как на скриншоте.

P. S. Где нарисовано красным, там должны быть отступы.

[image]

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/JKrmqK?editors=110  вот так , как бы ни чего сложного , учитесь

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/njwdg8om/  этот же пример на jsfiddle но с одним .post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

помести весь контент в див с классом например `content`. В CSS пишеш:

```
.content 
{
  margin:0 50px 0 50px;//top right bottom left
}
```

марджин задает отступы блока.. можно еще использовать `padding` - отступ задает внутри блока в таком случает нужно контент растянуть на всю страницу. Можна задать отступ в % тоже норм (`margin: 0 20% 0 20%;`)

Comment: Спасибо. Твой вариант самый понятный. Все получилось. Действительно все элементарно.

Answer (score 1):

Легче всего исспользовать фреймворк. Bootstrap 3. В его основе лежит сетка из 12 колонок.

Обязательные блоки:
1.Контейнер  
2.Строка 
3.Сетка

Подробнее почитай тут: http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php

Затем качай Brackets(с ним меньше гемороя), устанавливай emmet и в помощь тебе http://webdesign-master.ru/ но на его канале очень много полезного видео. Так же там есть стартовый шаблон для вёрстки.

Comment: Я думаю лучше сначала обучиться на чистом html. Потом будет легче. За ссылки спасибо

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY4rE9dstrJyJEghRkl7qfqdAdlyvaOVQ